# Error incompatible column type when using unionByName

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am a newbie to Spark SQL(using Scala) and have some basic questions regarding an error I am facing.
I am merging 2 data frames (oldData and newData) as follows

```
if (!oldData.isEmpty) {
      oldData
        .join(newData, Seq("internalUUID"),"left_anti")
        .unionByName(newData)
        .drop("all") //Drop records that have null in all fields
    } else {
      newData
    }
```

The error I see is

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types. ....
 at the 8th column of the second table;;
'Union
:- Project [internalUUID#342, TenantID#339, ObjectName#340, DataSource#341, product#343, plant#344, isMarkedForDeletion#345, distributionProfile#346, productionAspect#347, salesPlant#348, listing#349]
:  +- Join LeftAnti, (internalUUID#342 = internalUUID#300)
:     :- Relation[TenantID#339,ObjectName#340,DataSource#341,internalUUID#342,product#343,plant#344,isMarkedForDeletion#345,distributionProfile#346,productionAspect#347,salesPlant#348,listing#349] parquet
:     +- LogicalRDD [DataSource#296, ObjectName#297, TenantID#298, distributionProfile#299, internalUUID#300, isMarkedForDeletion#301, listing#302, plant#303, product#304, productionAspect#305, salesPlant#306], false
+- Project [internalUUID#300, TenantID#298, ObjectName#297, DataSource#296, product#304, plant#303, isMarkedForDeletion#301, distributionProfile#299, productionAspect#305, salesPlant#306, listing#302]
   +- LogicalRDD [DataSource#296, ObjectName#297, TenantID#298, distributionProfile#299, internalUUID#300, isMarkedForDeletion#301, listing#302, plant#303, product#304, productionAspect#305, salesPlant#306], false
```

The schema structure is as follows :
OldData

```
root
 |-- TenantID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ObjectName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DataSource: string (nullable = true)
 |-- internalUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- plant: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- isMarkedForDeletion: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- distributionProfile: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- productionAspect: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- productMovementPlants: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- unitOfIssue: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- productPlanningPlants: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- goodsReceiptProcessDuration: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- goodsIssueProcessDuration: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- mrpType: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- mrpController: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sourceOfSupplyCategory: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- abcIndicator: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salesPlant: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- loadingGroup: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- listing: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- validFrom: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- validTo: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- isListed: boolean (nullable = true)
```

and NewData

```
root
 |-- DataSource: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ObjectName: string (nullable = true)
 |-- TenantID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- distributionProfile: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- internalUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- isMarkedForDeletion: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- listing: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- isListed: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- validFrom: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- validTo: string (nullable = true)
 |-- plant: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- product: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- productionAspect: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- productMovementPlants: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- unitOfIssue: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- productPlanningPlants: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- abcIndicator: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- goodsIssueProcessDuration: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- goodsReceiptProcessDuration: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- mrpController: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- mrpType: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sourceOfSupplyCategory: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salesPlant: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- loadingGroup: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- internalRefUUID: string (nullable = true)
```

However I am not quite sure what does the "*8th column of the 2nd table*" denote? Moreover the columns are not ordered in the same way in both data frames. Is there any guidance on how to proceed on this?

Answer (score 0):

When using `unionByName` the order does not matter as it resolves using column names. But this is only applicable for columns at root (those returned by `df.columns`) and not the nested ones.

In your case, you get that error because you have some column types that don't match between the 2 dataframes.

We can take the example of column `listing`:

> newData => `array<struct<isListed:boolean,validFrom:string,validTo:string>>`
>
> oldData => `array<struct<validFrom:string,validTo:string,isListed:boolean>>`

In `StructType`, the order and the type of the fields is important. You can see it by using this simple code:

```scala
val oldListing = new StructType().add("isListed", "boolean").add("validFrom", "string").add("validTo", "string")
val newListing = new StructType().add("validFrom", "string").add("validTo", "string").add("isListed", "boolean")

oldListing == newListing
//res239: Boolean = false
```